# The "--host-0.0.0.0" option does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to setup my first Docker container in laravel.

Doing everything exactly like the tutorial, but on my PC I get
`The "--host-0.0.0.0" option does not exist.`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  backend:
     build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
     ports:
      - 8000:8000
     volumes:
         - .:/app
     depends_on:
       - db

  db:
    image: library/mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
    - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - 33066:3306
```

Comment: You have `--host=0.0.0.0` in your docker file but `--host-0.0.0.0` in your error. This looks to be a simple typo, yes?

Comment: Yes I spotted that typo and changed it to a `=`, but every-time I run `docker-compose up` I git this, so not sure how to clear the cache if that it what might be causing it.

Comment: Your volume mapping to `/app` is hiding the `/app` directory in the docker image. Try removing the volume mapping.

Comment: @HansKilian, could you please elaborate in a brief example. What would you change?
Just remove `     volumes:  - .:/app`?

Comment: Yes, I'd try removing it to see if it helps. Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks too @Tolis Gerodimos

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72349936/2240163

```
docker-compose up --build
```