# Docker Cashing, Not sure but new copy of project not starting

Tags: docker

I created the project and had  `--host-0.0.0.0` in the Docker file by accident.
I changed it too `--host=0.0.0.0`.
But every time I try to do  `docker-compose up` I am presented with this error

`The "--host-0.0.0.0" option does not exist.`

Is it cached somewhere or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild the image. Compose wont detect by default that the image should be re-built

Quotting from https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

> If you change a service’s Dockerfile or the contents of its build
> directory, run docker-compose build to rebuild it.

If you want to force it to rebuild, use

```
docker-compose up --build
```